# Copy fields of case class by using iteration over collection

Tags: scala, class, immutability, fold, iterable

I have few functions that change only one collection in case class per iter via copy method. Everything, works well when i use something like this `this.addA.addB.addC`. I thought that i can do the same with foldLeft on case class with copy method, unfortunately, it doesn't work in this case. Could you explain please:

1.Why fold's buffer always link to state and not on buffer from prev. iter?

2.How to implement such method?

```
case class SimpleState(list: List[String] = Nil) {

  def addA = copy(list = "4" :: list)
  def addB = copy(list = "5" :: list)
  def addC = copy(list = "6" :: list)
  val bufferABC = List("A","B","C")
  // must iterate over collection
  // expect "A","B","C","4","5","6" in result state
  // ordering doesn't matter
  def addABC = ???

  def addABCfold = bufferABC.foldLeft(this){case (state,str) =>
    state.copy(list = str::list)
  }

  def addABCiter = copy(list = bufferABC ::: list)
}
/////////////// output ////////////////////
val state = SimpleState()
val state2 = state.addA.addB.addC

val addABCfold = state.addA.addB.addC.addABCfold

val addABCiter = state.addA.addB.addC.addABCiter

state.addA.addB.addC.addABC
```

and ofc, output result:

> state: SimpleState = SimpleState(List())
>
> state2: SimpleState = SimpleState(List(6, 5, 4))
>
> addABCfold: SimpleState = SimpleState(List(C, 6, 5, 4))
>
> addABCiter: SimpleState = SimpleState(List(A, B, C, 6, 5, 4))
>
> scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing   at
>   scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(ws.sc2:280)  at
>   annette.exon.projects.project.wbs.A$A230$A$A230$SimpleState.addABC(ws.sc2:10)
>     at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(ws.sc2:25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly override the list in the copy by `str::list`, where `list` is the constant member from the enclosing class. You have to take `list` from the previous `state`:

```
case class SimpleState(list: List[String] = Nil) {

  def addA = copy(list = "4" :: list)
  def addB = copy(list = "5" :: list)
  def addC = copy(list = "6" :: list)
  val bufferABC = List("A","B","C")
  // must iterate over collection
  // expect "A","B","C","4","5","6" in result state
  // ordering doesn't matter
  def addABC = ???

  def addABCfold = bufferABC.reverse.foldLeft(this){
    case (state,str) =>
      state.copy(list = str::state.list)
  }

  def addABCiter = copy(list = bufferABC ::: list)
}
val state = SimpleState()
println(state.addA.addB.addC.addABCfold)
println(state.addA.addB.addC.addABCiter)
```

This outputs:

```
SimpleState(List(A, B, C, 6, 5, 4))
SimpleState(List(A, B, C, 6, 5, 4))
```

I don't see any advantages over simple `:::` though...

Comment: Spasibo tovarisch!

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov Pozhaluista, tovarischtsch, rad pomotsch! :]